# Return an array with only first 3 character/numbers from each item in an arrays

Tags: javascript, string, slice, digits

How can I return only the first 3 characters/digits from each item in an array?

For example: The string `123456` should return `123`, `987654` should return `987`, and so on.

Given an array of:

```
['7177576', '4672769', '2445142', '9293878', '5764392']
```

Expected return:

```
['717', '467','244', '929', '576']
```

I have tried `.slice()` but that returns the first three like this:

```
['7177576', '4672769', '2445142'].
```

Comment: use .str  .slice  etc

Answer (score 2):

[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) works for strings, too.

```js
 const
     data = ['7177576', '4672769', '2445142', '9293878', '5764392'],
     result = data.map(string => string.slice(0, 3));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has many [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for manipulating arrays. The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. As Nina Scholz mentions above you can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) on strings  as well.

The issue you are having is that you are calling slice on the array and not on the items of the array.

You need to do something like Nina [Suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70201983/1134764) which is to map over the main array and call your slice function for each item.

Comment: This is the explanation that Nina's post should have had. Apparently people like her style tho, she's made alot of her reputation on clever and concise answers using ES6 array methods that usually lack an explanation that would help beginners understand what's going on.